# javascript/jquery loop execute function after every iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var dagaData = ['Manok', 'Pusa', 'Daga', 'Ibon', 'Aso'];
$('#clicktest').on('click', function() {
    $.each(dagaData, function(index, item) {
        executeData(item);

        alert(item);
    });
});

function executeData(item) {
    var items = $("<div></div>").text(item);
    $('#pangtest').append(items);
}
```

Is it possible to execute the function on every iteration?

Right now when I run the code above it finished all iteration before the append happen.

That why I've put alert to see if every alert append each iteration.

Output of code above: `alert('Manok'), alert('Pusa') ,alert('Daga'), alert('Ibon'), alert('Aso')` executed append.

What I'm trying to achieve is `alert('manok') append, alert('Pusa') append, alert('Daga') append, alert('Ibon') append, alert('Aso') append`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, as it seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/396vj1mk/.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen why is it working on you, but on mine it doesn't,

Comment: You'll find it varies depending on the browser.

Comment: My bad. Should have tested cross-browser. It works on Firefox, but as @nnnnnn pointed out, some browsers do things differently.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen yeah my bad too, I opened your jsfiddle on firefox when I'm trying my code on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general sense, although the DOM is updated each time you call `.append()` the browser won't actually repaint the screen until after the entire JS function finishes. (Though *some* browsers will repaint at the point when an alert is open, which is why using `alert()` for debugging is a bad idea: it can subtly change the behaviour in a way that calling `console.log()` doesn't.)

You can work around this by using a `setTimeout`-based pseudo-loop - in between timeouts the browser then gets a chance to repaint:

```js
var dagaData = ['Manok', 'Pusa', 'Daga', 'Ibon', 'Aso'];

$('#clicktest').on('click', function() {
  var i = 0;  
  (function doNext() {
    var item = dagaData[i];
    executeData(item);
    alert(item);
    if (++i < dagaData.length)
      setTimeout(doNext, 5);
  })();
});

function executeData(item) {
    var items = $("<div></div>").text(item);
    $('#pangtest').append(items);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clicktest">Test</button>
<div id="pangtest"></div>
```

Or just use your original `$.each()` loop with the contents of the loop wrapped in a timeout, as per [Bnrdo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40033890/615754). But I prefer to wait to schedule each timeout only after the previous one is done because that way the order of execution is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in `setTimeout`

```
$.each(dagaData, function(index, item) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      executeData(item);

      alert(item);
   }, 1);
});
```

Comment: This is certainly a lot neater than my solution, so I've voted it up, but note that doing it like this doesn't guarantee that the updates will occur strictly in array index order.